# How can I add values found in a table for each id detected in a text field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has an `id` and a `value`, and another table that has `ids` on a single text field, for example:

Sql server version 14.0

```
id  id_value    grid    ids   xxxx 
1   3            1      1,3   xxxx
2   7            2      2     xxxx
3   5            3      2,3   xxxx
```

Desired output

```
Grid    ids   totalvalue 
1       1,3   8  
2       2     7  
3       2,3   12
```

Note: ignore dashes and underscores

Is there a way to add the value for each `id` found in the `ids` column, adding the `value` for each `id` found on the other table?

I'm currently doing it with a `datagridview` box in C# when I manage the data inside a program. However, I need to create a table to export the data and since the values change every few months. I will need to create a new table with SQL syntax that gives me the added value of the ids.

As per my example above, the column should have the values 8, 7, 12 on each column on the new table that would be created by that syntax.

Any ideas on how I can make this to work?

edit:

```
select sum(id_value) from dbo.table1 where dbo.table1.id in (select trim(value) from string_split(cast(ids as varchar), ','))) as totalvalue
```

i created a tableview that uses that code to set the value on my desired column and it seems to work

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The title mentions "word". Are you using that to identify an integer data type based on the underlying machine architecture or did you just choose to supply sample data and desired output that obscures the actual issues to be resolved?

Comment: I didnt know how to express the problem, basically the ids column is a text type that holds a different number of ids, and each id has its own value on a different table , in the end i would need to create a table with different columns but since the ids are in a single column i cant find a way to add the value of each id found in that text column to show the value on a different column and since in c# i only manage a simple "grid" or line of the table at a time and not the entire table i could add the value of each id detected with a datagridview.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this....

**Data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT,[value] INT ,grid INT, ids VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES   (1 ,3  ,1  ,'1,3')
        ,(2 ,7  ,2  ,'2')
        ,(3 ,5  ,3  ,'2,3')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT x.Grid
    , x.ids
    , SUM(t.value) TotalValue
FROM (
    SELECT 
           t.grid
         , s.NewIds
         , t.ids
    FROM @T t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM([value])) AS INT) AS [NewIds]
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.ids, ',') ) s
    ) x
INNER JOIN @t t ON t.id = x.NewIds
GROUP BY x.grid , x.ids
```

**Result Set**

```
grid    ids    TotalValue
1       1,3    8
2       2      7
3       2,3    12
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i couldnt manage to make it work as it is but it gave me some ideas in creating a view for the result table, i set up the thing that worked for me, thanks :)